# display selected value of the drop down in jsp page

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

I want to display selected value. In the text field I can display it within value like below

```
value ="<%=event_data.getE_venue()%>"
```

code :

```
<input type="text" name="where" placeholder="Add a place" size="23" value ="<%=event_data.getE_venue()%>"/>

<select name="category" value ="<%=event_data.getE_target_category()%>" id="single1">
     <option>Sports</option>
     <option>Corporate</option>
     <option>Religious</option>
     <option>Music</option>
</select>
```

but in dropdown box it doesn't work.
please help me. thanks..

Comment: i share my code on http://jsfiddle.net/wWbFh/

Comment: You might want to have a look at the attribute `selected` of the [select tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, select doesn't work in that way , you need to put selected attribute in option that matches your input.

for example:
 `<option selected='selected'>Sports</option>`

check this fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/ZLTS7/

your code should be something like :

```
<input type="text" name="where" placeholder="Add a place" size="23" value ="<%=event_data.getE_venue()%>"/>

<select name="category"  id="single1">
    <option  <%= (event_data.getE_target_category().equals("Sports")?"selected='selected'":"") %>>Sports</option>
    <option <%= (event_data.getE_target_category().equals("Corporate")?"selected='selected'":"") %>>Corporate</option>
    <option <%= (event_data.getE_target_category().equals("Religious")?"selected='selected'","") %>>Religious</option>
    <option <%= (event_data.getE_target_category().equals("Music")?"selected='selected'":"") %>>Music</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I TRIED THIS ONE. BUT IT GAVE A ERROR LIKE INCOMPLETE TYPE. REQUIRED BOOLEAN. FOUND STRING. CAN U HELP ME?

Comment: @user2599229 It should be `<%= (event_data.getE_target_category()=="Sports"?"selected='selected'","") %>` and so on

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the dropdown value through Javascript or jQuery. You can assign desired value to dropdown just like input

```
var dd = document.getElementById('single1');
var opts = ddl.options.length;
var value = <%=event_data.getE_venue()%>;
for (var i=0; i<opts; i++){
    if (dd.options[i].value == value){
        dd.options[i].selected = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

or if you are using jQuery.

```
$("#single1").val(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

See this example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#slectboxid option').click(function(){
    $('#textboxid').val($(this).val());
        });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form action="#" method="post">
<select name="select" id="slectboxid">
<option value="test">test</option>
<option value="test2">test2</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="text" id="textboxid" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```